# MCPE server using a mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ios, macos, hosting

I would like to run a Minecraft PE server that is hosted on my Mac. Is it possible to use port map and MAMP to host a server? I have already tried the port forwarding where I have to be on the world. I don't want it to be local i want it to be public.

Is there a way.

Comment: First of all, you don't need MAMP to host a local server. Minecraft has this function built-in. Second, as far as I can tell you can't run MC cross-platform unless it's the Windows 10 edition.

Comment: Is minecraft cross platform on mac. How Is this minecraft PE is still in alfa. @WillB.

Answer (score -1):

You should use https://www.pocketmine.net it a very reliable server fr MCPE !